# Not able to connect to internet using my wired network connection on my Dell inspiron N1401 laptop

Tags: 11.04, networking

I bought my new Dell N1401 inspiron laptop, installed Ubuntu 11.04. I have a wired internet connection works perfeclty on my desktop machine, when I plugged the cable to my laptop, it does not connect to internet.

I configured the IPv4 settings with the static IP address, but still I am not able to connect to internet. I have just started using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound strange, but go into network manager, and check that the network connection has a string (i.e. "Ubuntu")in the DHCP client ID field. Save this, and try the network connection again. Bizarrely this fixed the same issue for me. I think it might be something to do with the router rejecting empty client ids.